# Whoosh <Hit{}> Issue

Tags: python, search, django-haystack, whoosh

I'm working through the Whoosh [Quick start guide](http://packages.python.org/Whoosh/quickstart.html), and everything seems to be working except that I can't quite replicate the results in the guide.

I'm up to the bit about the [Searcher object](http://packages.python.org/Whoosh/quickstart.html#the-searcher-object) and when I run the code

```
print(results[0])
```

I don't get back an actual result if a match is found, I simply get back

```
<Hit {}>
```

whereas in the tutorial, the output is

```
{"title": "Second try", "path": "/b", "icon": "/icons/sheep.png"}
```

which is obviously quite a bit more helpful!

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

Figured it out.

For those who run into the same problem, I messed up by not explicitly stating that any of the items in my schema were stored - i.e. (stored=True).

Comment: Thank you! I was doing the same.